# Convert single df to multiple dfs by interchanging rows to columns and taking sum of each column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following pandas dataframe:

| Depts | Category | Monthly Booked | Monthly Delivered | Monthly Target | Yearly Booked | Yearly Delivered | Yearly Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HR | Human | 2345 | 2000 | 3000 | 1234556 | 234543 | 6432212 |
| Software | Engg | 654345 | 343213 | 765432 | 98765123 | 2345654 | 9999999 |
| Security | Human | 1234 | 1234 | 2000 | 23456 | 34568 | 234567 |
| Software | Engg | 12345 | 54334 | 324546 | 345645345 | 65345654 | 643563452 |
| Software | Human | 12345 | 54334 | 324546 | 345645345 | 65345654 | 643563452 |
| Security | Engg | 12345 | 54334 | 324546 | 34564534 | 65345654 | 643563452 |

Now I want to convert the values of `Depts` to column headers and group by `Category` and then take the Yearly and Monthly sums to two datatables along with total of each metric of each column.
Like below:

**Monthly Data**

| Category | Metric | Software | Security | HR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Engg | Target | 1089978 | 324546 |  |
|  | Delivered | 397547 | 12345 |  |
|  | Booked | 666690 | 54334 |  |
| Human | Target | 324546 | 2000 | 3000 |
|  | Delivered | 54334 | 1234 | 2000 |
|  | Booked | 12345 | 1234 | 2345 |
| Total | Target | 1414524 | 326546 | 3000 |
|  | Delivered | 451881 | 1234 | 2000 |
|  | Booked | 679035 | 55568 | 2345 |

**Yearly Data**

| Category | Metric | Software | Security | HR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Engg | Target | 653563451 | 643563452 |  |
|  | Delivered | 67691308 | 65345654 |  |
|  | Booked | 44410468 | 34564534 |  |
| Human | Target | 643563452 | 234567 | 6432212 |
|  | Delivered | 65345654 | 34568 | 234543 |
|  | Booked | 345645345 | 23456 | 1234556 |
| Total | Target | 1297126903 | 643798019 | 6432212 |
|  | Delivered | 133036962 | 65380222 | 234543 |
|  | Booked | 390055813 | 34587990 | 1234556 |

Can I do this using pandas functions? If yes, then how can I do it?
Note: I also want to keep the grouping but change indices to columns. Meaning I want to change the index names to column names but keep the grouping in the first two columns.

My present code - based on the answer given by @Code Different below:

```
tmp = df.set_index(["Category", "Depts"])
tmp.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(col.split(" ")) for col in tmp.columns], name=[None, "Metric"])
tmp = tmp.stack(level=1)

monthly = tmp.pivot_table(index=["Category", "Metric"], columns="Depts", values="Monthly", aggfunc="sum")

monthly = pd.concat([d.append(d.sum().rename(('Total', k))) for k, d in monthly.groupby(level=1)])
monthly = monthly.groupby(level=[0, 1], as_index=True).sum()
monthly.loc[:,'Total'] = monthly.sum(axis=1)
```

This keeps the multilevel index but if I use `reset_index` then the grouping is lost if I use `to_html` or `to_excel` functions. I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired based on the other answer's work:

```
def pivot_and_stuff(dataframe, values):

    tmp = dataframe.set_index(["Category", "Depts"])
    tmp.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(col.split(" ")) for col in tmp.columns], name=[None, "Metric"])
    tmp = tmp.stack(level=1)

    tmp = tmp.pivot_table(index=["Category", "Metric"], columns="Depts", values=values, aggfunc="sum")
    tmp2 = tmp.groupby(level=[1]).sum()
    tmp2['Category'] = 'Total'
    tmp2 = tmp2.set_index('Category', append=True).reorder_levels([1,0])

    dataframe = pd.concat([tmp, tmp2]).rename_axis('', axis=1).rename_axis(['Category', 'Metric'])
    dataframe = dataframe.reset_index().rename_axis('', axis=1)
    dataframe.Category = [i if not j else '' for i, j in zip(dataframe.Category.values, dataframe.Category.duplicated())]
    
    return dataframe

pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.0f}'.format)

df_m = pivot_and_stuff(df, 'Monthly')
df_y = pivot_and_stuff(df, 'Yearly')
print(df_m)
print()
print(df_y)
```

Output:

```
  Category     Metric   HR  Security  Software
0     Engg     Booked  NaN     12345    666690
1           Delivered  NaN     54334    397547
2              Target  NaN    324546   1089978
3    Human     Booked 2345      1234     12345
4           Delivered 2000      1234     54334
5              Target 3000      2000    324546
6    Total     Booked 2345     13579    679035
7           Delivered 2000     55568    451881
8              Target 3000    326546   1414524

  Category     Metric      HR  Security   Software
0     Engg     Booked     NaN  34564534  444410468
1           Delivered     NaN  65345654   67691308
2              Target     NaN 643563452  653563451
3    Human     Booked 1234556     23456  345645345
4           Delivered  234543     34568   65345654
5              Target 6432212    234567  643563452
6    Total     Booked 1234556  34587990  790055813
7           Delivered  234543  65380222  133036962
8              Target 6432212 643798019 1297126903
```

Comment: Actually this is almost similar to the output from the code that I have pasted. My problem is that `Category` and `Metric` are index names and not column names. If I do `to_html` and `to_excel`, `Category` and `Metric` are in one row and `HR`, `Security` and `Software` are in another row. But I want all of them to be my headers in one single header row. This is not happening.

Comment: @user001 I updated my answer based on the other answer's work. Us `index=False index_names=False` when exporting `to_html`.

Comment: I believe also you can use "index=True, merge_cells=True" as a parameter of the "to_excel" function to keep the index nice and merged like that. Idk about html though

Comment: This works! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```py
tmp = df.set_index(["Category", "Depts"])
tmp.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(col.split(" ")) for col in tmp.columns], name=[None, "Metric"])
tmp = tmp.stack(level=1)

monthly = tmp.pivot_table(index=["Category", "Metric"], columns="Depts", values="Monthly", aggfunc="sum")
yearly  = tmp.pivot_table(index=["Category", "Metric"], columns="Depts", values="Yearly", aggfunc="sum")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am not getting the `total` row in the tables.